# Having trouble satisfying a dependency during compilation

Tags: linux, makefile, dependencies, nfc, lz4

I apologize in advance, I am very new to using linux. I am attempting to install the proxmark3 client on Pop!OS and everything goes well up until I try to make all in the github repo. This is what I get.

```
me@pop-os:~/proxmark3$ make all

===================================================================
Version info:      Iceman/master/v4.17140-45-g6ddf28327
Platform name:     Proxmark3 RDV4
PLATFORM:          PM3RDV4
PLATFORM_FPGA:     xc2s30
PLATFORM_SIZE:     512
Platform extras:   No extra selected
Included options:  SMARTCARD FLASH -DRDV4 LF HITAG EM4x50 EM4x70 ZX8211 GENERAL_HF ISO15693 LEGICRF ISO14443b ISO14443a ICLASS FELICA NFCBARCODE HFSNIFF HFPLOT
Standalone mode:   LF_SAMYRUN
===================================================================
[*] MAKE client/all
===================================================================
Version info:      Iceman/master/v4.17140-45-g6ddf28327
Client platform:   Linux
GUI support:       QT5 found, enabled (Qt version 5.15.3 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu)
native BT support: Bluez found, enabled
Jansson library:   system library not found, using local library
Lua library:       system library not found, using local library
Python3 library:   Python3 not found, disabled
Readline library:  enabled
Whereami library:  system library not found, using local library
Lua SWIG:          wrapper found
compiler version:  cc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
===================================================================
[-] CC src/mifare/aiddesfire.c
[-] CC src/aidsearch.c
[-] CC src/atrs.c
[-] CC src/cmdanalyse.c
[-] CC src/cmdcrc.c
[-] CC src/cmddata.c
[-] CC src/cmdflashmem.c
[-] CC src/cmdflashmemspiffs.c
[-] CC src/cmdhf.c
[-] CC src/cmdhf14a.c
[-] CC src/cmdhf14b.c
[-] CC src/cmdhf15.c
[-] CC src/cmdhfcryptorf.c
[-] CC src/cmdhfepa.c
[-] CC src/cmdhfemrtd.c
[-] CC src/cmdhffelica.c
[-] CC src/cmdhffido.c
[-] CC src/cmdhffudan.c
[-] CC src/cmdhfgallagher.c
[-] CC src/cmdhfksx6924.c
[-] CC src/cmdhfcipurse.c
[-] CC src/cmdhficlass.c
[-] CC src/cmdhflegic.c
[-] CC src/cmdhfjooki.c
[-] CC src/cmdhflist.c
[-] CC src/cmdhflto.c
[-] CC src/cmdhfmf.c
[-] CC src/cmdhfmfdes.c
[-] CC src/cmdhfmfhard.c
src/cmdhfmfhard.c:33:10: fatal error: lz4frame.h: No such file or directory
   33 | #include <lz4frame.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:941: obj/cmdhfmfhard.o] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:177: client/all] Error 2
```

First I reinstalled the githb repo to see if that was the issue. I also made sure to install the lz4 package. I attempted to track down the cmdhfmfhard.o file to see where it was trying to pull the lz4frame file from, but I was unable to find it in the repo. I just manually searched through the files using cd. I did not find the file I was looking for  but I did find the lz4 directory which should contain the lz4frame.h file so I just manually copy and pasted the file into the lz4 directory. None of these solved this issue and I am worried I am barking up the wrong tree. Does anybody have any ideas on how to clear this dependency?

Comment: Since it has `<>` around the filename, it expects to find it in `/usr/include`. So I guess you were supposed to install that library first.

Answer (score 0):

Do this command first. Then it works.
(I had the same problem.)

```
sudo apt-get install liblz4-dev
```